# if/else statement is correct, but not returning incorrect

Tags: javascript, if-statement

These are my instructions:

have four arguments that are all number

return "correct" if the four numbers are a valid combination

return "incorrect" if the 4 numbers aren't a valid combination
a combination is valid if:

- the first number is a 3, 5, or 7
- the second number is 2
- the third number is between 5 and 100. 5 and 100 are both valid
  numbers
- the fourth number is less than 9 or greater than 20. 9 and 20 both
  invalid numbers

This is my code:

```
module.exports.checkLock = function(a, b, c, d) {

    if (a === 3 || 5 || 7, b === 2, c >= 5 || c <= 100, d < 9 || d > 20) {

        return "correct";
    }
    else {
        return "incorrect";
    }
};
```

And this is the error I am getting:

1) checkLock should return 'incorrect' for the incorrect first number example:

```
  AssertionError: expected 'correct' to deeply equal 'incorrect'
  + expected - actual

  +"incorrect"
  -"correct"

  at Context.<anonymous> (spec.js:39:49)
```

2) checkLock should return 'incorrect' for incorect second number:

```
  AssertionError: expected 'correct' to deeply equal 'incorrect'
  + expected - actual

  +"incorrect"
  -"correct"

  at Context.<anonymous> (spec.js:43:49)
```

3) checkLock should return 'incorrect' for invalid third numbers:

```
  AssertionError: expected 'correct' to deeply equal 'incorrect'
  + expected - actual

  +"incorrect"
  -"correct"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, sorry about formatting.

Comment: that's not how if statements work

Comment: Without testing, maybe `if ((a === 3 || a===5 || a===7) && b === 2 && (c >= 5 && c <= 100) && (d < 9 || d > 20)) {` is what you want? You can't use comma to separate the statements - you have to AND them together,

Comment: the comma operant is valid "The comma operator chains multiple expressions together, and the result of the operation is the value of the last operand. The only real use for it is when you need multiple side effects to occur, such as assignment or function calls."

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Is it though? What if the first three checks are false and the last is true? Wouldn't the result be true and incorrect?

Comment: i am just commenting on the syntax, not the logic of the expression

Answer (score 3):

First, you need compare `a` with the values you're checking - not just have them in another `||` expression.
Second, according to the text, **all** the conditions need to apply, so you need to use `and` operators:

```
module.exports.checkLock = function(a, b, c, d) {

    if ((a === 3 || a === 5 || a === 7)) &&
        (b === 2) &&
        (c >= 5 && c <= 100) &&
        (d < 9 || d > 20)) {

        return "correct";
    }
    else {
        return "incorrect";
    }

};
```

Comment: @jpw yes, you are correct. That was a momentary lapse in concentration on my side. Edited and fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

`if` clause doesn't work the way you wrote it in the first place. You can fix this by separating the statements in the following way:

`if (a === 3 || 5 || 7, b === 2, c >= 5 || c <= 100, d < 9 || d > 20)`

should be

`if ((a === 3 || a === 5 || a === 7)) && (b === 2) && (c >= 5 || c <= 100) && (d < 9 || d > 20))`

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
module.exports.checkLock = function(a, b, c, d) {
    if ( (a === 3 || a === 5 || a === 7 ) && ( b===2 ) && (c>=5 || c <=100) && (d<9 || d>20) ) {
        return "correct";
    }
    else {
        return "incorrect";
    }
};
```

working jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bq698wbu/

Answer (score 0):

For comparing multiple values with a variable, you can put them in array and compare using     `indexOf` , in this case for variable 'a' you can put in if conditional like : `[3,5,7].indexOf(a)` , this can be more useful if you have some large set of ordered numbers. Below solution should work:

```
module.exports.checkLock = function(a, b, c, d) {
if ( [3,5,7].indexOf(a) > -1 && ( b===2 ) && (c>=5 || c <=100) && (d<9 || d>20) ) {
    return "correct";
}
else {
    return "incorrect";
}
};
```